# What it means to be that liquid crystals are thermodynamically stable?

Tags: crystals, liquid-crystal

When we heat some solids, they don't pass into liquid state directly. Rather they form a mesomorphic phase called liquid crystals.Now when we heat liquid crystal, they are converted into pure liquids. But liquid crystal are said to be thermodynamically stable. I am not able to interpret it. What it means to be thermodynamically stable state ? And also how are they used in liquid crystal display?

Comment: Please check this link to know more about liquid crystals: http://www.uh.edu/~chembi/liquidcrystals.pdf

Comment: Thermodynamically stable means that the phase corresponds to a global free energy minimum.

Comment: May you explain in detail?

Comment: Is it related to temperature or heat something?

Answer (score 0):

Existing answer (Caetes) is good. A little more info:

Stability is all about the response of a system to small fluctuations.
A fluctuation in an isolated system could be, for example, a small movement of energy from one part of the system to another, or a small change in density as material moves from one part to another. If after such a fluctuation a system tends to be restored back its original state, then its condition is stable. The restoring process is something like a heat flow or an expansion or compression. The heat flows away from the hotter place; the region at higher pressure tends to expand, and so on.

The role of free energy here is that it is a useful way to track global entropy. As long as we use the correct free energy (the one dictated by the macroscopic constraints) then the equilibrium state occurs at an extreme value (usually a minimum) of the free energy.

For liquid crystals the aligned molecules are in a dynamic equilibrium. If the system fluctuates towards either pure liquid or pure solid then the free energy goes up (ultimately owing to all the energy movements and molecular interactions etc.) and this implies that the liquid crystal state is indeed an equilibrium state. It is not that the system is slowing freezing or slowly melting or something like that.